# References for methods for convergence analysis of discrete time dynamical systems with non lipschitz nonlinearity

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

Let a nonlinear dynamical system be described by the difference equations $$x(n+1)=f(n,x(n)),\ n\ge 0$$  with the function $f$ being nonlinear and non-lipschitz and bounded over a domain $D$. My question is

> Is there any general set of methods which can be used for stability analysis of this system?

I know that if $f$ is Lipschitz then there are many such methods, but I could not find any for the non-lipschitz case. I am just a novice in the field of nonlinear dynamical systems and I must admit I do not have the mathematical machinery required to start to think solving this kind of system from the scratch. This kind of thing is required for my research and after spending a lot of time I could not find examples of such systems analyzed in literature. So it would be very kind if anyone can give me some reference regarding this problem. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I think I should properly mention the type of analysis I want to find. Specifically, it would be quite helpful to me if I know some techniques regarding analysis of the behavior of the sequence $$\{\|x(n+1)-x(n)\|\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$

Comment: Can you point out which technique for Lipschitz functions is failing for your case ?

Comment: @nonlinearism, I do not know many Lipscitz techniques, but I was using the averaging technique, where I have formed an averaged system and was trying to show that the solution to the actual system is "quite close" to the averaged system. One technique for this, whose proof is given in page 319 of the book "Adaptive Systems" by Mareels and Polderman,  is captioned as the "Finite Horizon Averaging result". The proof requires the function to be Lipschitz continuous which is not in my case.

Comment: Which linear and bounded functions $f:(n,x)\mapsto f(n,x)$ do you have in mind? There are not many of these...

Comment: The functions $f$ that I have in mind are nonlinear, but they are bounded and non-Lipschitz, that is not *globally* Lipschitz, they maybe *locally* Lipschitz though, which I am not sure about.

Comment: Then why ask for the linear case, which is essentially empty?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant nonlinear, that was a mistake, I am correcting that.